# Dictionaries on iOS 8 not working

Tags: dictionary, ios

I just updated from iOS 7 to iOS 8, and I noticed that the built-in dictionaries, I previously used, aren't working. I had used American English, British English, and Apple Dictionary. Now, when I try to define any word, I get a "No definition found" error. The dictionaries I previously used show a blue circle (while all the others show the cloud download icon).

I tried to download a new dictionary, and I was able to use it. However, that was in another language.

How can I enable these dictionaries again?

Comment: Try the fix in the last posting at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6392686

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Deleting language doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: The circles are download progress indicators. Looks like iOS needs to re-download them after the update, and the somehow the download is stuck at 0%

Answer (score 2):

You can re-enable the apple dictionary by following this steps:

1. Tap on the word you want to define to select it and activate the popup.
2. Tap on Define to call up the dictionary.
3. Tap on Manage.
4. Now activate/download the Apple Dictionary or any other dictionaries you want.
5. Tap the X button beside any extra dictionaries you want to remove.

Now you should have your dictionary enabled again.

Comment: The previous dictionaries show blue circles，and you can not manage it.

Comment: In iOS 9, to delete a dictionary left swipe its entry in the list (there is no X button anymore).

Answer (score 2):

After updating to 8.0.2, the bug has been fixed!
:)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer (so your question comes off the unanswered list).

Comment: It this also in Apple's update description?

Comment: I Have the same problem on two different devices running 8.0.2. (Upgraded directly from 7 to 8.0.2)

Comment: I have he exact problem on an iPad, it first appeared in iOS 8, then with every update up till 8.1, the problem still exists.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with updating rather than the content of the update, so I don't believe this is a proper answer.